# Why is my app successfully deployed on netlify and fail on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, netlify

When I first **deployed** my **reactjs** app on **heroku** it was built **successfully**, but then it showed me an app **error**...
[image]
then I typed this command "**heroku logs --tail**" and it showed me the following error:

```
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.59.0 to 7.60.1.
 Error: Cannot find module './_baseToString'
 Require stack:
 - C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/lodash/toString.js
 - C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/lodash/capitalize.js
 - C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-               run/node_modules/cli-ux/lib/styled/table.js
 - C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-run/node_modules/cli-ux/lib/index.js       
 - C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-run/lib/lib/log-displayer.js
 - C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-run/lib/commands/logs.js
 -C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/plugin.js
 - C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/config.js
 - C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/index.js
 - C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js
 - C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/index.js
 - C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/bin/run
at Object.<anonymous>      (C:/Users/WailInfo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku/node_modules/lodash/toString.js:1:20)
```

*** The other problem is when I deployed my app on **netlify** it works properly

Answer (score 0):

I think For Heroku you should try the prestart npm script to build an app.

```
"scripts": {
 "prestart": "next build",
 "start": "next start -p ${PORT}",
}
```